# Cordova "Console" plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I added the plugin via

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
```

The i emulated on adroid the default project created (with device ready event demo)

In the logcat I see

```
I/chromium( 1330): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "Received Event deviceReady", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
D/PluginManager( 1330): exec() call to unknown plugin: Console
```

This is a problem because I've not trace of the line when console.log is invocated and this create some trouble when debugging.

This is my 'compacted' js code

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById("deviceready");
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event deviceReady');
    },

};

app.initialize();
```

Also, I'd like to know why a freshly new created prject is already giving an error !!

EDIT: I already tried to remove and re-add the plugin, but this has not fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and readding the plugin via `cordova plugin` doesn't work.

Simply, **install the plugin using npm**

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console
npm install cordova-plugin-console
```

After restartred android emulation of my cordova project, everything works.

Now I've the log row as expected (here splitted into 2 rows just for better readings):

```
I/chromium( 1416): [INFO:CONSOLE(36)] "Received Event deviceReady", 
source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (36)
```

Comment: @extempl: thanks for editing. `-i` in my windows version of npm works, but, of course, `install` is more explicit and documented.